# I Want to read the audio data, but there is an unhandled exception

Tags: c#

My code is like this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAnalisa.Text = "";
        string filename = txtSampel.Text;
        reader = new WaveFileReader(filename);
        int length = 1000;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

        reader.Read(buffer, 0, length);
        sample = new double[reader.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
        {
            sample[n] = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer,n);
            txtAnalisa.Text += n + ". Sampel = " + sample[n] + Environment.NewLine;
        }       
    }
```

but then when i run, there is an unhandled argument exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

What should i do?

Comment: Please wrap your code block with try {..} catch(){..} and post more data on Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have a clear error message:

> Destination array is not long enough

In your code there is only one array with hardcoded size and that is `buffer`. And the array is not long enough. As suggested in comments, the `length` variable should be bigger to increase `buffer` capacity.

Comment: but my wav file size is more than 1045 KB. When i use Reader length like:

for (int n = 0; n < reader.Length; n++)
            {
                sample[n] = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer,n);
                txtAnalisa.Text += n + ". Sampel = " + sample[n] + Environment.NewLine;
            }

its took a very long time to read the file because the reader length is more than 1 mllion